# Show that this knapsack algorithm can perform arbitrarily bad

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Show that this algorithm can perform arbitrarily badly, which is to say, for any α > 1,
there is a data set (n, c, W, V ) for which the actual maximum knapsack value is at least α
times as large as the value of the knapsack returned by the algorithm. Note that α itself
is should probably be a parameter to the data set you design.

```
function KP-O-APPROXIMATE(n,c,W,V)
    Initialize L as a list of n numbers
    for i from 1 to n do        Initialize the vector
        l_i <- 0
    end for
    repeat
       x <- 0 ; d <- 0 ; (x = 0 is the special "do nothing case")
       for i from 1 to n do 
          if l_i = 0 and w_i <= c_i then (check object can be taken)
              if v_i/w_i > d then
                   x <- 1; d <- (v_i / w_i)
              end if
          end if
        end for
        if x≠0 then       (Add selected object to knapsack)
             l_x <- 1; c <- c - w_x
        end if
    until x=0     (if x=0, no remaining objects)
    return L
 end function
```

I know if you input the following values, you will get a return that is not optimized.

n = 3

c = 100

W =[51, 50, 50]

V = [52, 50, 50]

However, I am having difficulty trying to use arbitrary values to make a set that would provide the same results.

EDIT:
If you take the set

n = 3

c = x

W = [(x/2 + 1), (x/2), (x/2)]

V = [a+1, a, a]

I believe this will always give you a not optimal solution. However, the correct solution is not a times as large as the incorrect solution. So I am looking to change the above dataset where the correct solution is always a times as large as the incorrect solution.

Comment: I see you have taken profit of my advice :)

Comment: You should recall what is the meaning of the 4 parameters in the context of a classical knapsack algorithm (many people have met this algorithm, but have forgotten details about it)

Comment: Could you explain in a few words what each section of the algorithm does (by adding comments for instance)?